# Open the app from an external link with universalLink or deeplink

Tags: swift, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I want to open app from an external link, for example a link that I get in `iMessage`, the question is, I should use `deepLink` or `universalLink`, I want to open the app when I tap on the link, then having ability to read the url in the app is enough for me.

And for this matter, I should set a Json file in the website as well? something like this:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-universal-links-in-your-app

It's a bit confusing for me, could anyone gives me a real example and steps?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, basically both the app itself and the website need to be aware that you are going to be using Universal Links. There are a few steps to do this:

First you need to include the website as an **Associated Domain** inside of your Xcode project.

Then for the website you do have to create what is known as the **apple-app-site-association** file. This lets the the website know which apps are associated with the website.

- This tutorial has a step by step on [How to setup your website to work Universal Links](https://www.kodeco.com/6080-universal-links-make-the-connection).

Lastly you will have to have to update your `AppDelegate` file to handle when a Universal link opens the application.

- More info can be found in the official Apple Documentation on [Creating Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/allowing-apps-and-websites-to-link-to-your-content).